Api Gateway giving 404 Error in spring cloud gateway
I have tried every thing to resolve still MY API Gateway is giving 404 error.If i am accressing Directly my PRODUCT Service it is NOT Giving any error.
I have made a product Service Which i am able to access Directly .But Not able to access it through Cloud Gateway
POM.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>3.2.7</version>
       <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>ApiGateway</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ApiGateway</name>
    <description>ApiGateway Services</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
       <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
       <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
       <connection/>
       <developerConnection/>
       <tag/>
       <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
       <java.version>17</java.version>
       <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
          <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com</groupId>
            <artifactId>ServiceDiscovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
          <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
             <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
             <type>pom</type>
             <scope>import</scope>
          </dependency>
       </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

application.properties

spring.application.name=API-GATEWAY
server.port=9090

eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address =true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true

management.endpoint.gateway.enabled=true
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= gateway
spring.main.web-application-type=reactive

##API Gateway routing Feature
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled.lowerCaseServiceId=true



application.yml
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id : PRODUCT-SERVICE
          uri : lb://PRODUCT-SERVICE
          predicates :
            - Path=/products/**



ApiGatewayApplication

package com.ApiGateway;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class ApiGatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(ApiGatewayApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("API Gateway is Running....");
    }

}

Api GateWay Should work as Expected

which request are you sending exactly that is returning you 404?

And what is successful directly?

I means if i am trying to access my Product service .i am able to do so but not through api gateway
